# Can't update my Database using Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I've just started to learning about `CodeIgniter`. But I stuck some point. After 7+ hours work and  googling I decided to ask here. I am trying to update the database but I couldn't get out of it. After I enter data my data don't update.  Here's my code ;

***Takvim_Model.php***

```
  function __construct() { 
     parent::__construct(); 
  } 

  public function insert($data) { 
     if ($this->db->insert('takvim', $data)) { 
        return true; 
     } 
  } 

  public function delete($roll_no) { 
     if ($this->db->delete('takvim', 'roll_no = '.$roll_no)) { 
        return true; 
     } 
  } 

  public function update($data,$old_roll_no) { 
     $this->db->set($data); 
     $this->db->where('roll_no', $old_roll_no); 
     $this->db->update('takvim', $data); 
  } 
} 
?>
```

***Takvim_View.php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang = "en">   <head> 
  <meta charset = "utf-8"> 
  <title>Takvim Example</title>    </head>    <body> 
  <a href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/takvim/add_view">Add</a>

  <table border = "1"> 
     <?php 
        $i = 1; 
        echo "<tr>"; 
        echo "<td>Sr#</td>"; 
        echo "<td>Roll No.</td>"; 
        echo "<td>Name</td>"; 
        echo "<td>Start Time</td>"; 
        echo "<td>Stop Time</td>"; 
        echo "<td>Update</td>"; 
        echo "<td>Delete</td>"; 
        echo "<tr>"; 

        foreach($records as $r) { 
           echo "<tr>"; 
           echo "<td>".$i++."</td>"; 
           echo "<td>".$r->roll_no."</td>"; 
           echo "<td>".$r->name."</td>"; 
           echo "<td>".$r->start_time."</td>";              
           echo "<td>".$r->stop_time."</td>"; 
           echo "<td><a href = '".base_url()."index.php/takvim/update/"
              .$r->roll_no."'>Update</a></td>"; 
           echo "<td><a href = '".base_url()."index.php/takvim/delete/"
              .$r->roll_no."'>Delete</a></td>"; 
           echo "<tr>"; 
        } 
     ?>
  </table>
```

***Takvim_Controller.php***

```
<?php
class Takvim_controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function index() {
        $query = $this->db->get("takvim");
        $data['records'] = $query->result();

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('Takvim_view', $data);
    }

    public function add_event_view() {
        $this->load->helper('form'); 
        $this->load->view('Takvim_add'); 
    }

    public function add_event() {
        $this->load->model('Takvim_model');
        $data = array (
            'roll_no' => $this->input->post('roll_no'),
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'start_time' => $this->input->post('start_time')
        );

        $this->Takvim_model->insert($data);

        $query = $this->db->get("takvim");
        $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
        $this->load->view('Takvim_view',$data); 
    }

    public function update_event_view() { 
     $this->load->helper('form'); 
     $roll_no = $this->uri->segment('3'); 
     $query = $this->db->get_where("takvim",array("roll_no"=>$roll_no));
     $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
     $data = array('records' => $data['records']);       
     $this->load->view('Takvim_update',$data); 
    } 

    public function update_event(){ 
     $this->load->model('Takvim_Model');

     $data = array (
            'roll_no' => $this->input->post('roll_no'),
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'start_time' => $this->input->post('start_time'),
            'stop_time' => $this->input->post('stop_time')
    );
     $old_roll_no = $this->input->post('old_roll_no'); 
     $this->Takvim_Model->update($data,$old_roll_no); 

     $query = $this->db->get("takvim"); 
     $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
     $this->load->view('Takvim_view',$data); 
    }

    public function delete_event() { 
     $this->load->model('Takvim_Model'); 
     $roll_no = $this->uri->segment('3'); 
     $this->Takvim_Model->delete($roll_no); 

     $query = $this->db->get("takvim"); 
     $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
     $this->load->view('Takvim_view',$data); 
    } 
} ?>
```

***Takvim_Update.php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang = "en">  <head>       <meta charset = "utf-8"> 
  <title>Takvim Example</title>    </head>   <body> 
  <form method = "" action = "">        
     <?php 

        echo form_open('Takvim_controller/update'); 
        echo form_hidden('old_roll_no',$records[0]->roll_no); 
        echo form_label('Roll No.'); 
        echo form_input(array('id'=>'roll_no',
           'name'=>'roll_no','value'=>$records[0]->roll_no)); 
        echo "
        "; 

        echo form_label('Name'); 
        echo form_input(array('id'=>'name','name'=>'name',
           'value'=>$records[0]->name)); 
        echo "
        ";
        echo form_label('Start Time'); 
        echo form_input(array('id'=>'name','name'=>'name',
           'value'=>$records[0]->start_time)); 
        echo "
        ";
        echo form_label('Stop Time'); 
        echo form_input(array('id'=>'name','name'=>'name',
           'value'=>$records[0]->stop_time)); 
        echo "
        "; 

        echo form_submit(array('id'=>'submit','value'=>'Edit')); 
        echo form_close();
     ?> 

  </form>
```

***Routes.php***

```
$route['takvim'] = "Takvim_controller"; 
$route['takvim/add'] = 'Takvim_controller/add_event'; 
$route['takvim/add_view'] = 'Takvim_controller/add_event_view'; 
$route['takvim/update/(\d+)'] = 'Takvim_controller/update_event_view/$1'; 
$route['takvim/delete/(\d+)'] = 'Takvim_controller/delete_event/$1';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Please take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions.
If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck a description of the problem with your code. It should include a [**Minimum**, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: seems, you don't need `$this->db->set($data);` if you use that array in `$this->db->update('takvim', $data); `

Answer (score 0):

The name of model is not recomanded for Codeigniter 
When you name a model use `_model` not `_Model` (This create conflit in your code)

Answer (score 0):

In `Takvim_Update.php` you are submitting the form to `'Takvim_controller/update'` and I can't see the `update` method in your `Takvim_controller` or the `Takvim_controller/update` route in your `routes.php` file.

First edit your `Routes.php` and add new route to your update method in `Takvim_controller`.

```
$route['takvim/update'] = 'Takvim_controller/update_event';
```

Then in `Takvim_Update.php` file submit your from to `takvim/update` url.

```
 echo form_open('takvim/update');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:i hope it will help.
define routes.

```
$route['takvim/update/(:any)'] = 'Takvim_controller/update_event_view/$1';
```

//controller
first get data from table.and then update by whatever paramete's you want to update. for example i am giving primary key id of table.

```
$data=array(
'roll_no' => $this->input->post('roll_no'),
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'start_time' => $this->input->post('start_time'),
            'stop_time' => $this->input->post('stop_time')
);
$this->Takvim_Model->update($id);
```

//model

```
function update($id){
return $this->db->where('id',$id)->update('table_name',$data);
}
```